# How can I change ArrayAdapter to global and clear it in another class?

Tags: android

I have a `ArrayAdapter` declaration. I want to clear it and add some other data.
So how can I change it to global?

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastArray;
    // ...
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    mForecastArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastArray);
}
```

Another class

```
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        if (strings!=null){
            mForecastArray.clear();
        for (String dayForecast : strings){
            mForecastArray.add(dayForecast);
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't use `mForecastArray` in the second class

Comment: Create a singleton class where your arraylist is, and use set/get methods to do what do you want with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are always error prone and create issues in the long run.

You can have a `listener` defined in your `AsyncTask` that would have say a method `updateAdapter` and this listener would be implemented by your `Fragment` `ForecastFragment`. So once you you have

```
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

    FetchListener listener;

    public FetchWeatherTask(FetchListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface FetchListener {
        public void updateAdapter(String[] arr);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
        //if (strings!=null){
        //  mForecastArray.clear();
        //for (String dayForecast : strings){               
            //mForecastArray.add(dayForecast);
        //}

        // just call your listener's update method
        listener.updateAdapter(strings);
    }
}
```

**Inside ForecastFragment:**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements FetchWeatherTask.FetchListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // say if you are starting your AsyncTask here
        new FetchWeatherTask(this).execute();
    }

    public void updateAdapter(String[] arr) {
        if (arr!=null){
            mForecastArray.clear();

        // use arr to re populate your mForecastArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create your custom application refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

create static `ArrayList` in `onCreate` of your custom application. 
You can access that `ArrayList` anywhere in application.